# IsResizing or equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a way to check during a resizing event whether the control is currently being resized or whether it has reached its final size. (C# Windows Forms)

E.g. In Java with sliders, you can tell whether the user is currently sliding or whether they have released the mouse - this means that you can avoid expensive redraws or other calculations until the final value has been chosen.

Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: I worded the question as I wanted it, it is not 'The Grand User's' fault that the API only fires these events on top level controls (sometimes known as Forms).

Comment: Fred - the question you asked did not specify that you wanted only the top level control (ALWAYS known in WinForms as a "Form") it simply said (and still says) "...whether the control is currently being resized..." I'd expect if your question was intended to only get these events on a very specific control, especially one as common as the primary top level control of the entire framework, you'd have worded it that way. If you'd like I'd be happy to edit your question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Form has a few events to help you with this

There's the [ResizeBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin.aspx), [Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx), and [ResizeEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx) Events. A combination of them should get you what you want.

Further notes:

When you click and drag the border of a window, the event sequence is ResizeBegin, repeated Resize for each move of the mouse, ResizeEnd. When you minimize, maximize or restore the window size, then Resize is called once for each of those. A ResizeBegin and ResizeEnd pair is also called for simply moving the window around as well by the title bar, though not when you programatically set the windows Location property.

Comment: Thanks mate, perfect answer. In my case I have MDI forms so it gets a little trickier because the ResizeBegin is not fired when the parent form is resized but the but I think I can work around that.